# SQL Server procedure/function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, date, procedure

Is possible to have a procedure or function that will be "triggered" when some date is reached?

I have a procedure (triggers are off for this case and in general, their meaning is not for this case) that calculates the interval between two dates and if the interval is bigger than 30 days, there is an update that updates a third column. That is fine and it works.

As an addition, I would like to have a possibility that the procedure will somehow read the second date column (that date is a later date than the first one) and when by the sys, that date is reached, activate procedure or job.

So case in numbers is;

Table `Date`:

- "Date1" - 01.01.2022.
- "Date2" - 28.02.2022.
- "Status" - In progress

When "Date2" is reached in the system, activate the procedure and change Status to "Done"

Do you have any solution for this case? As I said, triggers are off for this because of the limitation of another system.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a scheduled task (such as by using SQL Server agent) to run the procedure daily to process the rows for that day.

Comment: If this is the desired logic then you can do it in the `SELECT` queries that access the table rather than updating what is stored. `CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= Date2 THEN 'Done' ELSE Status END`

Comment: _Is possible..._ Short answer is no. The passage of time does not automatically trigger anything within the database engine. But why bother with this at all - use a computed column?

Comment: I've got it with the Case function that Martin suggested. Tested with wrong and correct dates and it works. Also, will use SQL Server agent or Win Task scheduler for the daily jobs!

Thank you guys!

Comment: Piling on basically. Scheduling, that's what we're talking about, should be done outside of the database. The database isn't about scheduling. Use a scheduler.

Comment: SQL Server Agent job is what you are looking for